# With `docker build` is it possible to get both the build log and the ID of the generated image on stdout/stderr?

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I know `docker build ...` writes all the log from the builder out to command line while `docker build --quiet ..` doesn't *but prints the resulting image ID instead*.

Both is very important IMHO, can I get both?

There is also `--idfile` which can supply but forces me to provide and clean up a file name.

Is there also a way to get both, the image ID *and* the build log just via stdout/err instead?

Docker version is 25.0.3 with BuildKit enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try pipe approach

> docker build . | tee build.log | awk '/Successfully built/{print $NF}'

Comment: This was my approach, too, but with BuildKit enabled, this line does not get printed anymore..
There is a line `writing image sha256:fea1ca3c561e4bf263a67d49dc0117aa327efa2939bbc6dd941d1694f8196232 done` though, but it's implementation specific